# Remove a row in Python Dataframe if there are repeating values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, duplicates

This might be a quite easy problem but I can't deal with it properly and didn't find the exact answer here. So, let's say we have a Python Dataframe as below:

df:

ID a b c d
0  1 3 4 9
1  2 8 8 3
2  1 3 10 12
3  0 1 3 0

I want to remove all the rows that contain repeating values in different columns. In other words, I am only interested in keeping rows with unique values. Referring to the above example, the desired output should be:

ID a b c d
0  1 3 4 9
2  1 3 10 12

(I didn't change the ID values on purpose to make the comparison easier). Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare `length` of `set`s with length of columns names:

```
lc = len(df.columns)

df1 = df[df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) == lc, axis=1)]
print (df1)
    a  b   c   d
ID              
0   1  3   4   9
2   1  3  10  12
```

Or test by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
df1 = df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated().any(), axis=1)]
```

Or [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df1 = df[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(lc)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[[len(set(x)) == lc for x in df.to_numpy()]]
```